# c++ filling matrix boost

Tags: c++, algorithm, boost, matrix, fill

hi i've looked into the vector duplicate of this but couldn't find answer

```
ublas::matrix<int> input;
fill(input.begin1(), input.end1(), in_val);
fill(input.begin2(), input.end2(), in_val);
```

but it gives me

> [2,3] {(3,3,3) (3,0,0)}

as you can guess i just want to fill all of it with `init_val=3` , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

matrix has constructor for it.

```
ublas::matrix<int> input(2, 3, 3);
```

does what you want

Answer (score 0):

use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix.htm#scalar_matrix

you can also use array storage, `matrix.data()` which is range concept (began/end) directly, but I think it is not good idea in general

Comment: sorry tht's not working (error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘((Layer<int>*)this)->Layer<int>::input = in_val’
/usr/include/boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp:184: